# How to get all value from foreach loop into database in C#. Avoiding multiple entry into database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, for-loop

What i intend to do is to insert the value into SQL database table. Firstly, let me explain the flow. I generate dynamic textboxes on the Form. Next, while inserting all the values from other textboxes and comboboxes i do no have any problem. But to get all the values entered manually from dynamically created textboxes was a challenge for me. Which i managed to fix it using the following code.

```
        foreach (TextBox textbox in this.panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            string message_0 = "";
            message_0 = textbox.Text.ToString();

        }
```

But when i insert the values into the database using the insert query i face a problem into database. The value gets inserted with the duplication of other columns too if i place the for loops curly braces after the sql commands.

```
        foreach (TextBox textbox in this.panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            string message_0 = "";
            message_0 = textbox.Text.ToString();





        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    string a = "insert into new_product (name, description, image, fk_type, date, reference, field_value) values ('" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + richTextBox1.Text + "' ,@images ,'" + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "',  '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-mm-yy") + "','" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + message_0 + "') ";
                    cmd.CommandText = a;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@images", images));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    table_update();

          }
```

Is it normal in this case or am i doing anything wrong here. Any help would be appreciated guys. Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYk7A.png)

Comment: You dont need to create new command in a loop - just provide a new value.  All in all a DataGridView seems like it would be easier than dynamic controls, and a DataTable makes updates trivially simple

Comment: What is your expected behavior? You're inserting a new row as part of the foreach loop. Are you trying to horizontally insert data for each text box? You can't (shouldn't) dynamically create columns. Either have one column with a comma-separated list of these textbox values, or use a document store. Alternatively you can have a junction table with a PK of your product table and a list distinct list of these textboxes.

Comment: Is field_value changing? That is the only value that changes.  Why are calling table_update() in a loop?

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code is wide open to sql injection. Don't want to invite bobby tables over for dinner. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: you are right @PoweredByOrange we can't dynamically create columns. But the idea of creating a table to store the list referencing to PK of product table seems a good alternative.

Comment: Hi @Paparazzi field_value is changing every time in the loop.  And table_update() is a method to update the datagridview table.

Comment: OK what do you expect?  The only value you are changing in the loop is string message_0.   Again why do you need table_update() IN the loop?

Comment: Hi @SeanLange apparently i am trying to learn from mistakes. Thank you. Will research on using parameterized queries.

Comment: @Paparazzi i placed a datagridview table to see the database data. And that method would display the database data onto datagridview on the page. Well that is not at all a problem. According to my question when i insert the data i get multiple entries and how can i avoid it.

Comment: You avoid it by not inserting multiple entries.   Update in a loop is a problem.  Sorry I tried to help.